# Binding Collection Error

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

I have a VB6 program that uses ADO Data Controls on a number of forms. The data in the various textboxes on the forms is bound to the ADODC via the .DataSource and .DataField properties.

Usually, these ADODCs cause us no problems. However, during some migration testing, the following error was discovered on *some* computers:

"Binding Collection Error"
"Field not updatable, Bound Property Name: Text, Field Name: Decimal_Delimiter"

This does not occur on all computers, and isn't entirely reproduce-able.

The only decent lead I've been able to find is in this [article](http://objectmix.com/basic-visual/155027-binding-collection-error-resolved.html). It indicates that installing MS Access may fix the problem.

Has anyone seen this error before? If installing Access is the trick, what does installing Access do to fix it? (If I knew that, I could potentially check for a missing file, etc)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one or more of the PCs you have been testing have an out of date version of Active Data objects, or maybe a mixture of different version. I am guessing that installing Access also installs a later version of ADO (Access 2000 installs ADO 2.1). You don't need to install Access (the comment about DAO is a red-herring). If you are running software on Windows 2000, then you should upgrade to the last version of [Microsoft Data Access Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components) (MDAC 2.8). Windows XP should be upgrade to the latest service pack to get these components.

If you are targeting Windows Vista and above, then Windows DAC 6.0 should already be installed. Unfortunately, this is binary incompatible with earlier versions of ADO, and you have to recompile.

Follow [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components) for a Wikipedia article about this.

Use [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793) to download MDAC 2.8 if you have Windows 2000.
If you are using Windows XP, download the latest service pack.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  Unfortunately, we are having trouble duplicating the problem to try and fix it. However, if it happens again we will be sure to try your suggestions.